# Create a vector in R with double or triple values

Tags: r

I need to have a vector with a fixed number of elements e.g. 20. Usually I would take:

```
x0 <- 1
seq(x0, 560, 1)
```

Right now I want to have each number double to triple:

```
x<-(1,1,2,2,3,3,...)
```

or

```
x<-(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,...)
```

Looking like this but automatically generation, because I need too many elements.

Comment: look at `?rep` and pay attention to `each` parameter.

Comment: Regarding the 'fixed number of elements' also check `length.out` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution as per @Arun:

```
x<-rep(c(1,2,3),3)
```

Comment: Works - I did it like this: `l<-length(x)/4 ; x0 = 1 ;
n<-seq(x0, l, 1) ;
sample<-rep(n,1,each=4)`