# create new vector from existing vectors by using "rep"

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following two vectors,

```
a<-c(2,3,5)
b<-c(1,3,2)
```

Now I want to create a new vector *c* with this results from *a* and *b*,

```
2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5
```

I tried this code, but it just does not work, I am stocked here. Help please. How can I get the results showed above?

```
for (i in 1:3){
 c<-rep(a[i], each=b[i])
}
```

Comment: Could the downvoters please provide some constructive comments? I think this question is clearly stated.

Comment: @bdemarest In my experience, many people will down vote questions that they perceive as being trivially answered by the documentation/Google/etc.

Comment: @bdemarest ?`rep`, third and fourth example

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037660/create-a-vector-in-r-with-double-or-triple-values/18037760#18037760)

Comment: @bdemarest Thank you guys. First time using R, even don't know where for help~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rep(a,b)` is what you're looking for.